# How to add new rows to a pandas dataframe with data calculated from the previous row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to add 5 new rows to an already existing dataframe, and base numbers in each of those new rows from a calculation of the item behind it.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df.tail()
```

|  | period | value2 | fieldName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 2021 | 3.87 | eps |
| 19 | 2022 | 3.97 | eps |
| 20 | 2023 | 4.245 | eps |
| 21 | 2024 | 4.565 | eps |

I now want to add 5 new rows to the end of the dataframe and calculate a few new data items for each of the rows based on the previous row. I would like to add 1 to the index, period, and value items.

The dataframe needs to look like the following:

|  | period | value2 | fieldName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 2021 | 3.87 | eps |
| 19 | 2022 | 3.97 | eps |
| 20 | 2023 | 4.245 | eps |
| 21 | 2024 | 4.565 | eps |
| 22 | 2025 | 5.565 | eps |
| 23 | 2026 | 6.565 | eps |
| 24 | 2027 | 7.565 | eps |
| 25 | 2028 | 8.565 | eps |
| 26 | 2029 | 9.565 | eps |

Notice though, that the fieldName column does not change.

I've read appending new new dataframe for each row is extremely slow, and I've seen scenarios of added a numpy array to the end, but I haven't seen any examples of calculating the new row from the previous row.

What would be the most efficient way to write this in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do ( basically create a df with last row repeated n times, then add [1, 2, ...n] to `period` and `value2` columns.

```py
    n = 5
    temp = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[-1]]*n)
    temp['period'] = temp['period'].add(np.arange(n+1)[1:])
    temp['value2'] = temp['value2'].add(np.arange(n+1)[1:])
    out = pd.concat([df, temp], ignore_index=True)
```

print(out):

```py
       period  value2 fieldName
    0    2021   3.870       eps
    1    2022   3.970       eps
    2    2023   4.245       eps
    3    2024   4.565       eps
    4    2025   5.565       eps
    5    2026   6.565       eps
    6    2027   7.565       eps
    7    2028   8.565       eps
    8    2029   9.565       eps
```